# Running bash script in backend safe?

Tags: node.js, shell, security, command-line

Hi I am pretty new to web security and am worried about possible shell/command injection risks. I am wondering if it is safe to run a command line script only in my nodejs backend and have the web host run it.

From my understanding, it would be safe to run as the backend is not able to be accessed from the website and its front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my understanding, it would be safe to run as the backend is not able to be accessed from the website and its front end.

That is essentially correct, but I would rephrase it to:

> It is safe to run a shell script from your web server as long as the parameters you are passing to the shell script are either hard-coded or server-generated values.

Shell-injection happens when you take strings that came from the web user, and pass them as parameters to the exec call. It is possible to do that safely, but you'll need to carefully sanitize or escape the input to make it command-line safe, but this is a bit tricky and hard to do correctly since the list of "dangerous characters" that you need to sanitize / escape is different in bash vs zsh vs powershell, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just to clarify, if no user input from my front end ends up being in the shell script then I am completely safe?

Comment: Yes, I would say so, because there's no way for a user outside the server to cause that script to do anything unexpected (see footnote 1).

Comment: footnote 1: I'm just a random dude on the internet and have not inspected your code. I am not legally responsible if it turns out to not be "completely safe".

Comment: Thanks again and of course your not responsible for my code! Last question, would login credentials in my shell script be safe and not visible to users?

Comment: @Tris That should also be ok as far as leaking out through the web app to web users. However putting credentials in shell scripts tends to be a no-no because it's too easy to accidentally check that file into git, or someone emails the source code around, or otherwise have it "walk away". A better practice is to read creds from env vars and have the admins place them there.